# If $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function on $[0,1]$ , find polynomials $\{f_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $||f-f_n||_{L^1_{[0,1]}}\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $f\in L^p$ is supported on $[0,1]$ , can we find a sequence of polynomials $\{f_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $||f-f_n||_{L^1_{[0,1]}}\to 0$ ?
My attempt:
We use $L^p$ denote $L^p_{[0,1]}$ for simplicity . If $f\in L^2$ , then let $$S_Nf(x)=\sum_{-N}^N a_n e^{- inx}$$ and by Weierstrass's approximation theorem we can find $f_n$ such that $||f_n-S_nf||_{L^{\infty}} \le \frac 1n$ , then by Holder inequality we get $$||f-f_n||_{L^1} \le ||f-f_n||_{L^2}||1||_{L^2} \le (||f-S_nf||_{L^2}+||S_nf-f_n||_{L^2})||1||_{L^2}\to 0$$ Since $[0,1]$ has finite measure , if $p \ge2$ then $f \in L^p$ implies $f \in L^2$ , so we only need to check the condition when $p \lt 2$ . But for $p \neq 2$ , $L^p$ is not  a Hilbert space , we can not get $$||f-S_Nf||_{L^p}\to 0$$ Does the conclusion still valid for $p \lt 2$ ?

Comment: How do you choose the $a_n$?

Comment: @Severin Schraven $a_n =\int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2 \pi inx} \, dx$ , the fourier coefficient of $f$ .

Comment: Ah ok. Your claim still holds true for $p\geq 1$. You have to approximate by first by a sequence of continuous functions (if you have not seen this before: first approximate by simple functions, the simple functions by simple functions with open support (for this you have to use the regularity of the Lebesgue measure) and then those by continuous functions). Then you can use Stone-Weierstrass to approximate your continuous functions by polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for the help , but what about the condition when $p \lt 1$ ?

Comment: The proof goes through for $0<p<1$. You have just to keep in mind that you do not have the triangle inequality, but $$ \Vert f + g \Vert_{p} \leq 2^{\frac{1}{p-1}} (\Vert f \Vert_p + \Vert g \Vert_p $$ there is no other point where you need anything about the $p$.

Comment: @ Severin Schraven I see it , thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stone-Weierstrass theorem states that any continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ may be approximated uniformly by a polynomial $p$. That is, given $\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}\eps > 0$ there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |g(x) - p(x)| < \eps$.

Lusin's theorem tells you that continuous functions are dense in $L^1([0,1])$. That is, for any $f \in L^1([0,1])$ and any $\eps > 0$ there exists a continuous function $g$ defined on $[0,1]$ for which $\|f-g\|_{L^1} < \eps$.

Start with $f \in L^1([0,1])$ and $\eps > 0$.  Choose $g$ and then $p$ accordingly.  Then
$$\|f-p\|_{L^1} \le \|f-g\|_{L^1} + \|g-p\|_{L^1} \le \|f-g\|_{L^1} + \|g-p\|_{L^\infty} < 2\eps.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help . For the proof of Lusin's theorem used  the inequality $||f+g||_{L^1} \le ||f||_{L^1}+||g||_{L^1}$ , which is not true when $p \lt 1$ . So how to deal with this ?

Comment: Your question *specifically* asks for polynomials $f_n$ with $\|f - f_n\|_{L^1} \to 0$. What is the role of $p < 1$?

Comment: Sorry , what I really what to ask  is the condition $p \lt 2$ .I

Comment: Lusin's theorem works in $p=1$.

Comment: Yes , it works in $p \ge 1$ , but I'm not sure when $p \lt 1$ .